# Is it possible to deploy Datadog agents on AWS EKS cluster using terraform

Tags: cluster, terraform, amazon-eks, datadog

I am looking to understand if anyone can guide me on how to install Datadog agents on my AWS EKS cluster as pods. I am able to complete my requirement by using kubectl commands.

But here I am looking for a possible solution to do the same work from Terraform script or if someone can suggest any other automated way to deploy Datadog agents on my eks cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Helm Provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest/docs) for Terraform can be used to deploy packages to Kubernetes. This [GitHub issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-helm/issues/428) contains an example how to use it to deploy the Datadog agent:

```
resource "helm_release" "datadog" {
  name          = "datadog"
  version       = "1.38.2"
  chart         = "stable/datadog"
  namespace     = kubernetes_namespace.datadog.metadata.0.name
  recreate_pods = true
  force_update  = true

  values = [<<YAML
image:
  repository: datadog/agent
  tag: 6.14.1-jmx
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
clusterAgent:
  containerName: cluster-agent
  image:
    repository: datadog/cluster-agent
    tag: 1.3.1
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  enabled: true
  metricsProvider:
    enabled: true
  replicas: 1
  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: 200m
      memory: 256Mi
    limits:
      cpu: 400m
      memory: 512Mi
datadog:
  apiKeyExistingSecret: datadog-api-key
  apmEnabled: true
  appKeyExistingSecret: datadog-app-key
  collectEvents: true
  env:
    - name: DD_APM_IGNORE_RESOURCES
      value: "GET /webjars/.*, GET /v2/api-docs, GET /swagger-resources, GET /actuator/health, GET /_health, GET /manifest"
    - name: DD_KUBELET_TLS_VERIFY
      value: "false"
    - name: DD_COLLECT_EC2_TAGS
      value: "true"
    - name: DD_CUSTOM_SENSITIVE_WORDS
      value: "authorization"
    - name: DD_LOGS_CONFIG_K8S_CONTAINER_USE_FILE
      value: "true"
  leaderElection: true
  logsConfigContainerCollectAll: true
  logsEnabled: true
  logLevel: INFO
  name: datadog
  nonLocalTraffic: true
  processAgentEnabled: true
  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: 500m
      memory: 512Mi
    limits:
      cpu: 2000m
      memory: 2Gi
  tags:
    - env:${var.environment}
    - cluster:<my_cluster>
  confd:
    disk.yaml: |-
        init_config:
        instances:
          - use_mount: true
            mount_point_whitelist:
              - /$
    vault.yaml: |-
        init_config:
        instances:
          - api_url: https://<some_vault_url>/v1
    istio.yaml: |-
        init_config:
        instances:
          - istio_mesh_endpoint: http://istio-telemetry.istio-system:42422/metrics
            mixer_endpoint: http://istio-telemetry.istio-system:15014/metrics
            galley_endpoint: http://istio-galley.istio-system:15014/metrics
            pilot_endpoint: http://istio-pilot.istio-system:15014/metrics
            citadel_endpoint: http://istio-citadel.istio-system:15014/metrics
            send_histograms_buckets: true
            send_monotonic_counter: true
  useCriSocketVolume: true
daemonset:
  enabled: true
  tolerations:
    - key: "node-role.kubernetes.io/controlplane"
      operator: "Exists"
      effect: "NoSchedule"
    - key: "node-role.kubernetes.io/controlplane"
      operator: "Exists"
      effect: "NoExecute"
    - key: "node-role.kubernetes.io/etcd"
      operator: "Exists"
      effect: "NoExecute"
    - key: "node-role.kubernetes.io/<node_taint>"
      operator: "Exists"
      effect: "NoSchedule"
  useConfigMap: true
  customAgentConfig:
    listeners:
      - name: kubelet
    config_providers:
      - name: kubelet
        polling: true
    apm_config:
      enabled: false
      apm_non_local_traffic: true
    jmx_use_cgroup_memory_limit: true
    logs_config:
      open_files_limit: 500
  updateStrategy:
     type: RollingUpdate
  useHostPort: true
kubeStateMetrics:
  enabled: true
kube-state-metrics:
  rbac:
    create: false
  serviceAccount:
    create: false
    name: "${kubernetes_service_account.kube-state-metrics.metadata.0.name}"
rbac:
  create: false
  serviceAccountName: "${kubernetes_service_account.datadog-cluster-agent.metadata.0.name}"
YAML
  ]

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      keyring,
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: How to add multiple repositories for a chart like a dogwatch requires two repos should be added to the helm.